# tratando de levantar el servidor con nodemon, me sale este error

Tags: nodejs

```
$ npm run nodemon


tesis_bdup@0.8.4 nodemon /home/alforhanz/MisProyectos/tesis_bdup
nodemon ./bin/www
[nodemon] 1.17.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
sequelize deprecated String based operators are now deprecated. Please use Symbol based operators for better security, read more at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:242:13
Port 3001 is already in use
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: El error es muy claro te esta indicando que el puerto 3001 esta en uso.
Sería útil saber que sistema operativo estas ocupando.

Answer (score -1):

tuve el mismo problema, revisando la documentación solo encontré el comando $npx nodemon y el npm start, a mi me funciono el primero.

para mas informacion visita los comandos de nodemon https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon

espero te sea util